# How can I get a csv file from a dataframe in .txt large file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to get a .txt to a .csv file from a data frame, and I made some code but it shows only 10457 rows and 1 column, instead 10457 rows and 18650 columns, appears that all columns convert in only one.

I've tried in Jupyter notebook

```
   import os
   import pandas as pd

   save_path = "/Users/Desktop/Python-testing"

   in_filename = os.path.join(save_path,'/Users//Desktop/Python- 
   testing/data_gene_sample_report.txt')
   out_filename = os.path.join(save_path,'Output.csv')

   df = pd.read_csv(in_filename, delimiter=";")
   df.to_csv(out_filename, index=False)
```

I expect the output of like this, (a csv file)

```
Column 1    -------------------- Column2 --------- Column 3------....



-0.6431287095785616                
-0.6431287095785616               
-0.6431287095785616               
-0.6431287095785616              
-0.1893300604823005              
-0.6431287095785616
```

… but instead, I have this

```
0   -0.6431287095785616\t-0.9447514405913471\t1.08...
1   -0.6431287095785616\t-0.8505859268683292\t0.52...
2   -0.6431287095785616\t-0.30176910768817655\t0.1...
3   -0.6431287095785616\t-0.42440145633072285\t-0....
4   0.1893300604823005\t-1.0091233999680644\t-0.09...
5   -0.6431287095785616\t-1.0796556228003118\t-0.0...
```

Comment: can you provide first few lines of the .txt? are you sure the delimiter is `;`?

Comment: check pandas version as it should output columns by default

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the first few lines of your text file. We could then copy / paste it and test your code.